# Passing session variables while using rewrtite-target annotation in Ingress

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

In my ingress I have used `target-rewrite` annotation which is domain B service which loads in background when domain A front end loads.

How can I pass session variables/header which I give while login to domain A which is front end.

Currently, when I open front end (domain A) I enter my credentials, again it asks for credentials when it rewrite-targets to domain B in background.
Any help/inputs will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Will [sticky sessions](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/affinity/cookie/#sticky-sessions) help you?

Answer (score 0):

[rewrite-target](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#rewrite) it is only used to change the URI address:

> `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` - Target URI where the traffic must be redirected    string.

Here is example yaml:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: rewrite
  namespace: default
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: rewrite.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /something(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: http-svc
            port: 
              number: 80
```

> In this ingress definition, any characters captured by  `(.*)`  will be assigned to the placeholder  `$2`, which is then used as a parameter in the  `rewrite-target`  annotation.
>
> For example, the ingress definition above will result in the following rewrites:
>
> - `rewrite.bar.com/something`  rewrites to  `rewrite.bar.com/`
> - `rewrite.bar.com/something/`  rewrites to  `rewrite.bar.com/`
> - `rewrite.bar.com/something/new`  rewrites to  `rewrite.bar.com/new`

Taking this into account, you are only able to operate on variables that will be included in the URI. Then you will have to set the appropriate capture group and then refer to it (similarly to the example presented above).

Another solution for storing some information (variables) is to use the sticky sessions. You can find all the necessary information and examples [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/affinity/cookie/#sticky-sessions).

Comment: Thanks Mikolaj. rewrite-target works fine for me. But the issue is when it rewrite target to other domain service, I get authentication popup which I want to remove. I have tried using sticky sessions, but didnt worked.

Comment: So please [react on answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it was helpful. For your authentication popup please create [another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post) on stackoverflow.

Comment: And what exactly did you try with sticky sessions?

Comment: I tried adding  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity-mode: "balanced"  to ingress

Comment: And what's the result? Do you have any errors?